# Pandas: KeyError when using column names which are included in an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have text files that I'm parsing which contain fixed width fields with lines that look like this:

```
USC00142401201703TMAX  211  H  133  H  161  H  194  H  206  H  161  H  244  H  178  H-9999     250  H   78  H   44  H   67  H   50  H   39  H  106  H  239  H  239  H  217  H  317  H  311  H  178  H  139  H-9999     228  H-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
```

I'm parsing these into a pandas DataFrame like so:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def read_into_dataframe(station_filepath):
    
    # specify the fixed-width fields
    column_specs = [(0, 11),   # ID
                    (11, 15),  # year
                    (15, 17),  # month
                    (17, 21),  # variable (referred to as element in the GHCND readme.txt)
                    (21, 26),  # day 1
                    (29, 34),  # day 2
                    (37, 42),  # day 3
                    (45, 50),  # day 4
                    (53, 58),  # day 5
                    (61, 66),  # day 6
                    (69, 74),  # day 7
                    (77, 82),  # day 8
                    (85, 90),  # day 9
                    (93, 98),  # day 10
                    (101, 106),  # day 11
                    (109, 114),  # day 12
                    (117, 122),  # day 13
                    (125, 130),  # day 14
                    (133, 138),  # day 15
                    (141, 146),  # day 16
                    (149, 154),  # day 17
                    (157, 162),  # day 18
                    (165, 170),  # day 19
                    (173, 178),  # day 20
                    (181, 186),  # day 21
                    (189, 194),  # day 22
                    (197, 202),  # day 23
                    (205, 210),  # day 24
                    (213, 218),  # day 25
                    (221, 226),  # day 26
                    (229, 234),  # day 27
                    (237, 242),  # day 28
                    (245, 250),  # day 29
                    (253, 258),  # day 30
                    (261, 266)]  # day 31

    # create column names to correspond with the fields specified above
    column_names = ['station_id', 'year', 'month', 'variable',
                    '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',  
                    '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',  
                    '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30',  '31']
    
    # read the fixed width file into a DataFrame columns with the widths and names specified above
    df = pd.read_fwf(station_filepath, 
                     header=None,
                     colspecs=column_specs,
                     names=column_names,
                     na_values=-9999)

    # convert the variable column to string data type, all others as integer data type
    df.dropna()  #REVISIT do we really want to do this?
    df['variable'] = df['variable'].astype(str)

    # keep only the rows where the variable value is 'PRCP', 'TMIN', or 'TMAX'
    df = df[df['variable'].isin(['PRCP', 'TMAX', 'TMIN'])]

    # melt the individual day columns into a single day column
    df = pd.melt(df,
                 id_vars=['station_id', 'year', 'month', 'variable'],
                 value_vars=['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',
                             '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',
                             '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'],
                 var_name='day', 
                 value_name='value')

    # pivot the DataFrame on the variable type (PRCP, TMIN, TMAX), so each
    # type has a separate column with the day's value for the type
    df = df.pivot_table(index=['year',
                               'month',
                               'day'],
                        columns='variable',
                        values='value')

    return df
```

I now get the DataFrame in the shape I want it, except that there are rows for days that don't exist (i.e. February 31st, etc.), and which I'd like to remove.

I've tried to do this using masks, but when I've done so I get a KeyError when I try to use what I think are valid column names. For example if I include the following code in the above function before returning the DataFrame I will get a KeyError:

```
months_with_31days = [1, 3, 7, 8, 10, 12]
df = df[((df['day'] == 31) & (df['month'] in months_with_31days))
        |
       ((df['day'] == 30) & (df['month'] != 2))
        |
       ((df['day'] == 29) & (df['month'] != 2))
        |
       ((df['day'] == 29) & (df['month'] == 2) & calendar.isleap(df['year']))
        | 
        df['day'] < 29]
```

The above will result in a KeyError:

```
KeyError: 'day'
```

The day variable was created by the melt() call, then used within the index in the call to `pivot_table()`. How this affects the indexing of the DataFrame and why it messes up the ability to use the previous column names is not clear to me.

### Edit

I assume that I now have a MultiIndex on the DatFrame, created as a result of the call to `pivot_table()` via using an index argument.

Initial lines displayed when printing the DataFrame:

```
variable         PRCP   TMAX   TMIN
year month day                     
1893 1     01     NaN   61.0   33.0
           02     NaN   33.0    6.0
           03     NaN   44.0   17.0
           04     NaN   78.0   22.0
           05     NaN   17.0  -94.0
           06     NaN   33.0    0.0
           07     NaN    0.0  -67.0
```

I've tried referencing the DataFrame's columns using dot notation instead of brackets with quoted column names, but I get similar errors. It seems like the year, month, and day columns have been merged into a single index column and can no longer be referenced individually. Or maybe something else is going on here? I'm stumped, and wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: you can find the column names by doing `your_df_name.columns.values`. What are your columns there?

Comment: Thanks for this idea. DataFrame column values: ['PRCP' 'TMAX' 'TMIN']
DataFrame index names: ['year', 'month', 'day']. Seems like I've moved the year, month, and day columns/labels into the index. This wasn't my actual intention, I really want to have a normal index along with actual year, month, and day columns, which are useful for doing further paring down of the data as with the removal of rows representing non-existent days. I've tried to call both the pivot_table() and melt() functions above in various different ways but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: Can you show the header of the final df? It might be multindexed which means you cannot do df['day']

Comment: I think you're right, I may have a MultiIndex now. I'm not at work now so can't yet display the header, but it does look similar to many of the MultiIndex examples I've seen so this is likely the case. So I have a MultiIndex now in which the top level is year, next is month, then last is day. ...

Comment: ... My assumption is that there are year, month, and day values for each row in the DataFrame, but these aren't proper columns now (fields in the MultiIndex instead) and as such can't be referenced using bracket notation. If this is true then what is the correct notation to use for referencing these values, so I can use them to filter out rows for invalid/non-existent days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've created a multi-index DataFrame.  From looking at your output (without having access to your data), you should be able to access the days by typing:

```
df['variable']['day']
```